# Not getting correct results when using ado.net

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am getting some very strange results, when I am trying to run a stored procedure using ado.net. I have verified that the stored procedure executes correctly when I execute it using `EXEC dbo.AddressSearch`.

```
public DataTable ExecuteStoredProcedure(string name, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
        var dataTable = new DataTable();
        var mode = _configurationService.AppSetting("mode");
        var connectionString = _configurationService.ConnectionString($"{mode}ConnectionString");

        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();

            using (var command = new SqlCommand(name,sqlConnection))
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue(parameter.ParameterName, parameter.Value);
                }

                using (var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataTable;
}
```

Here is the code that is calling the stored procedure; I have verified that it is calling the stored procedure using SQL Server Profiler. Below is what it is sending:

```
exec sp_executesql 
N'AddressSearch',
N'@PageSize int,
@Start int,
@StreetName nvarchar(4000),
@Notes nvarchar(4000),
@ParcelNumber nvarchar(4000),
@ZoningCode nvarchar(4000),
@HouseNumber nvarchar(2),
@County nvarchar(4000),
@Municipality nvarchar(4000)
,@SubDivision nvarchar(4000)',
@PageSize=50,
@Start=1,
@StreetName=N'',
@Notes=N'',
@ParcelNumber=N'',
@ZoningCode=N'',
@HouseNumber=N'12',
@County=N'',
@Municipality=N'',
@SubDivision=N''
```

So I went in and debugged this with SSMS and I noticed that the variables are not being set. Can anyone please tell me why this would happen?

Json being sent.

```
{
    "county":"",
    "esn":"",
    "houseNumber":"12",
    "municipality":"",
    "notes":"",
    "page":"1",
    "pageSize":"50",
    "parcelNumber":"",
    "start":"0",
    "streetName":"",
    "subDivision":"",
    "uniqueId":"",
    "zoningCode":""
}
```

Populating all json:

```
{
    "county":"a",
    "esn":"12",
    "houseNumber":"12",
    "municipality":"",
    "notes":"notes",
    "page":"1",
    "pageSize":"50",
    "parcelNumber":"abd",
    "start":"0",
    "streetName":"3",
    "subDivision":"sub",
    "uniqueId":"1",
    "zoningCode":"15"
}
```

Sent to SQL Server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'AddressSearch',N'@PageSize int,@Start int,@StreetName nvarchar(1),@Notes nvarchar(5),@ParcelNumber nvarchar(3),@ZoningCode nvarchar(2),@HouseNumber nvarchar(2),@County nvarchar(1),@Municipality nvarchar(4000),@SubDivision nvarchar(3),@Esn int,@UniqueId int',@PageSize=50,@Start=0,@StreetName=N'3',@Notes=N'notes',@ParcelNumber=N'abd',@ZoningCode=N'15',@HouseNumber=N'12',@County=N'a',@Municipality=N'',@SubDivision=N'sub',@Esn=12,@UniqueId=1
```

Stored procedure:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'AddressSearch') AND TYPE IN (N'P',N'PC'))
    DROP PROCEDURE dbo.AddressSearch
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddressSearch
    @PageSize INT = 50,
    @Start INT = 1,
    @StreetName NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @Esn INT = NULL,
    @Notes NVARCHAR(500) = '',
    @ParcelNumber NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @ZoningCode NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @HouseNumber NVARCHAR(25) = '',
    @County NVARCHAR(100) = '',
    @Municipality NVARCHAR(50) = '',
    @UniqueId INT = NULL,
    @District INT = NULL,
    @SubDivision NVARCHAR(100) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
        SELECT 
            Id
            , HouseNumber
            , StreetName
            , EsnNumber
            , PropertyDescription AS Description
            , TotalAddress
            , PointType
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(Id)) AS RowNumber
        FROM
            dbo.AddressJoinedToAllTables
        WHERE 
            (StreetName LIKE '%' + @StreetName + '%' OR @StreetName = '')
            AND (Notes LIKE '%' + @Notes + '%' OR @Notes = '')
            AND (ParcelNumber LIKE '%' + @ParcelNumber + '%' OR @ParcelNumber ='')
            AND (Zoning LIKE '%' + @ZoningCode + '%' OR @ZoningCode = '')
            AND (HouseNumber LIKE '%' + @HouseNumber + '%' OR @HouseNumber ='')
            AND (County LIKE '%' + @County + '%' OR @County = '')
            AND (Municipality LIKE '%' + @Municipality + '%' OR @Municipality ='')
            AND (SubDivision LIKE '%' + @SubDivision +'%' OR @SubDivision = '')
            AND (CAST(EsnNumber AS NVARCHAR) LIKE '%'+ CAST(@Esn AS nvarchar) + '%' OR @Esn IS NULL)
            AND (CAST(District AS NVARCHAR) LIKE '%'+ CAST(@District AS nvarchar) + '%' OR @Esn IS NULL)
            AND (Id = @UniqueId OR @UniqueId IS NULL)
    )
    SELECT 
        Id
        , HouseNumber
        , StreetName
        , EsnNumber
        , Description
        , TotalAddress
        , PointType
    FROM
        CTE
    WHERE 
        RowNumber BETWEEN @Start AND (@Start + @PageSize-1)
END
```

Comment: One reason would be you're not populating the `Parameters[]` parameter when you call the `ExecuteStoredProcedure` function.

Comment: all of the parameters are being populated correctly.

Comment: And you know this how?

Comment: Not necessarily a fix, but you already have an array of parameters, use `command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);` instead of looping.

Comment: try `command.Parameters.Add(parameter);`

Comment: That "JSON being sent", how do you map that to the `SqlParameter`s?

Comment: Also set the command as `CommandType.StoredProcedure`

Comment: @Crowcoder I did that originally. just switched to make sure values were being sent.

Comment: so I just added what was being sent, is there an issue with sproc, because all values are being sent?

Comment: Did you catch my comment about `CommandType.StoredProcedure` ???

Comment: no i didnt, i will try that thank you

Comment: that is what it was. thank you.